# Tasks parallelism slower than normal execution?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, task

I'm a little bit confused because when i use this code :

```
catalog.Elements = GetElements(myProvider.Elements);
catalog.Programs = GetPrograms(myProvider.Programs);
catalog.Details = GetDetails(myProvider.Details);
```

i have 4 seconds.

And when i try to do it with tasks (.NET 4.0) :

```
Task<List<Element>> elementsTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Element>>(
    delegate { 
        return GetElements(myProvider.Elements); 
    });
Task<List<Program>> programsTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Program>>(
    delegate { 
        return GetPrograms(myProvider.Programs); 
    });
Task<List<Detail>> detailsTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Detail>>(
    delegate { 
        return GetDetails(myProvider.Details); 
    });

catalog.Elements = elementsTask.Result;
catalog.Programs = programsTask.Result;
catalog.Details = detailsTask.Result;
```

I get 6 seconds.

Is it normal that it is faster when I don't use the task parallelism ?

Thanks

Comment: how are you measuring the time?

Comment: With the Stopwatch class

Comment: what do the methods use? sql server?

Comment: i have a Pentium Dual-Core CPU and i'm executing it in a console project.

Comment: What is the code for your Get* methods?  Are the algorithms I/O bound or CPU bound?

Comment: it all depends on how much work is actually done in these tasks and whether its CPU or IO bottle necked

Comment: It's probably because of the extra indentation on the second code block. That slows it down, donch'a know ;)

Comment: Do we even know if these are running in parallel? Doesn't the TPL reserve the right to run things synchronously when it deems fit?

Comment: For your information, i logged each entry to the methods and i confirm the methods are executed in parallel mode.

Comment: I have commented the block where i assign the result of the task and now i stop the watch after that all tasks are finished (with IsCompleted property) and it's speeder (1 second).

Answer (score 6):

Parallelism takes many forms. It depends entirely on the underlying hardware and the problem you are trying to "parallelise".

In your case, you could be getting resource contention at the CPU level. How many cores? Shared cache? Computationally expensive routines? Very light routines, so the overhead of threading outweighs the gains? Are the routines accessing shared state?

Plenty of questions. Basically, don't assume that parallel code runs faster.

<strike>Sorry this isn't an answer to your performance issues, but to do that you would need to explain what each routine is doing.</strike>

On the upside, I'll make the optimistic assumption that you have done the good thing and profiled the two pieces of code. Your profiling has told you that "parallelising" (note, not paralyzing :-P) the code yields no benefit so can be avoided in favour of simpler synchronous code.

***Actually***, to answer your question: yes it can be normal, but requires understanding the problem you are attempting to parallelise. Don't take this one example as an indication of performance to be expected from the TPL. I'm always eating humble pie when it comes to mistakes or assumptions I make with asynchronous code...

Comment: In this code, i'm just preparing new objects with a content that i have already loaded so no call to a database only data manipulating

Comment: @ahikaz Depending on the hardware, if the runtime decides to farm out to different threads, the threads will contend for CPU time with each other. On multi-core systems, this is often not seen. On a single core system, you can see the context switching done in order to give threads time-slices to work in. This switching costs. This is more noticeable on computationally intensive tasks.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yeah, but I'm guessing this is all performance locally based on the OPs various comments.

Comment: I'm trying in my methods only to create new objects with data that i have loaded before. And of course, i will not take it as an example for the performance of tasks but i thougt that i will get a better execution time or the same as the sequential mode

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just stacking threads on your two cores by blindly creating new tasks you should use the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` method, since that already does some performance tweaking like thread recycling and load balancing.